# 3D barchart bug

Tags: r, shiny, 3d, bar-chart, echarts4r

I am trying to generate a 3D barchart using the `echarts4r` library but I can see an issue where it is accepting only x-axis as single letter.

See below working example:

```
library(echarts4r)

data <- data.frame(
  x = c("A"
        ),
  y = c(1
        ),
  z = c(
    35820
        )
)

e_charts(data, x) %>%
  e_bar_3d(y, z) %>%
  e_x_axis_3d(type= "category") %>% e_y_axis_3d(type= "category") %>% e_z_axis_3d(type= "value")
```

the screenshot for the working example:
[image]

This the example that does not generate the barchart

```
library(echarts4r)

data <- data.frame(
  x = c("HS"
        ),
  y = c(1
        ),
  z = c(
    35820
        )
)

e_charts(data, x) %>%
  e_bar_3d(y, z) %>%
  e_x_axis_3d(type= "category") %>% e_y_axis_3d(type= "category") %>% e_z_axis_3d(type= "value")
```

See x-axis is not well displayed:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Agree that this looks like a bug. A workaround would be to use a list column. To this end I use a `tibble` instead of a `data.frame` and wrap the x axis category in `list`:

```
library(echarts4r)
library(tibble)

data <- tibble(
  x = list("HS"),
  y = c(1),
  z = c(
    35820
  )
)

e_charts(data, x) %>%
  e_bar_3d(y, z) %>%
  e_x_axis_3d(type = "category") %>%
  e_y_axis_3d(type = "category") %>%
  e_z_axis_3d(type = "value")
```

[image]